# Run Redis server as service on Window 10?

Tags: redis, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I was able to run the redis server through the Windows Subsystem for Linux following this guide: https://medium.com/@RedisLabs/windows-subsystem-for-linux-wsl-10e3ca4d434e.

But I do not fully understand how the subsystem works. I thought it would run the server on Windows and I could see this in the Windows Services which is not the case. Can someone tell me how to run Redis as a service.

EDIT

Does someone know if there is a standard way to download and install Redis for windows other than using the WSL? I have seen some guides, but they are outdated.

Comment: This thread may help: https://superuser.com/q/1343558